# How to extract data from a csv and put it in a text file in java

Tags: java, csv, text

I am trying to have a program that takes certain data from a csv and puts it in certain lines of my text file. My csv had multiple rows/columns for each Sale. It looks like:

> Sale, Number, Code, Delivery, Date (with the values underneath the headings)
>   Sale1, 3333, 3213, May18, Arp10

My text file needs the data from the csv on certain times it says "type" so I have it as: 
Key "tab"
Key "tab"
Type " "

My code is:

```
public static void ChangeFile () throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\C:\\Users\\READ.txt\\"));

 Scanner s = new Scanner(br);
 for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
       String word = "type";
 int totalCount = 0;
 int wordCount =0;

 while (s.hasNext()){
     totalCount++;
     if(s.next().equals(word)){
         wordCount++;
     }
   }

//  int counter = 0;
// 
 ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

System.out.println("word count: " + wordCount);
       System.out.println("total count"+ totalCount);

   }

} }
```

I have functions above this that also read in the text file and the csv. I didn't know if a for each would work where all the words in the text file are stored in an array and a for each for the work "type" and putting a count on the types. Right now it is just counting the amount of type words that show up. Note: I do not need every single type replaced just a few need data added to it after the word. Struggling with getting the data from the csv.

My code for importing my csv is:

```
try

{

ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>(); 

File csvFile = new File("C:\\Users\\book1.csv\\"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile)); 

String line = ""; 

StringTokenizer st = null; 

int lineNumber = 0; 

int tokenNumber = 0; 

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 

String[] arr = line.split(",");
arr = line.split(" "); // gets rid of space


//for the first line it'll print
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){


//String.format("%-10s",arr[i]);
System.out.println(arr[i]+" " ); // h
}
lineNumber++;

//use comma as token separator 
System.out.println();
} 
} 


catch(IOException ex) { 

ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a library for reading CSV files

Comment: I wasn't sure what library to use and how to download/use it

Comment: I always use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).
 You can see how to use it [here](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/)

Comment: After I download the OpenCSV how do I implement it? or do I put an import in my code? I download the file and put it in my source packages in my program but dont know what to do next

Comment: please find a tutorial online that explains how to add libraries to your project

Answer (score 1):

You should just use proper parser as it's more reliable.

[univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) is WAY faster than using `line.split(",");`, and will handle things such as quotes, line endings and delimiters in your fields. It also clears the whitespace you are having trouble with by default.

Try this code:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.detectFormatAutomatically();

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new File("C:\\Users\\READ.txt"));
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)